# How do I edit a value in Main() with a function in the same class?

Tags: c#

So I'm trying to take a value from Main(), edit it with a function, then keep the changed value.

EDIT:

```
    static void Divisors(int i, int count)
    {
        while (i % 2 == 0 && i != 0)
        {
            divisors[count] = i/2;
            count++;
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i = 10;
        int count = 0;
        int[] divisors = new int[1000];
        
        Divisors(i);
        
        return count;
    }
```

Wanted Output: whatever it counted

Actual Output: 0

Comment: Check [ref (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref).

Comment: Pass array as argument `static void Divisors(int i, int count, int[] divisors)` and call `Divisors(i, count, divisors);` - as easy as it can be because array is reference type to pass its content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parameters are passed by-value in C#, so you can't assign new values to them and have them affect the original arguments passed to them like that. You could instead return a value from `Change`, and assign it to `i` in the `Main` method:

```
static int Change(i)
{
    return i + 2;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int i = 0
    i = Change(i);
}
```

Comment: I suspect `return i + 2;` (for the value passed in) would be a closer example to the code in the question

Comment: @MarcGravell with OP's latest edit, I agree. Edited accordingly.